# Unable to create an actor using UnTypedActorFactory of akka java api

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I am trying to create an actor with untyped actor factory, compilation happens fine. But while running the application, I get the following error. Am I missing anything in configuration?

Java Code:

```
MyActor myactor = new MyActor();  //MyActor extends UnTypedActor
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("mynamespace");
ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
      public UntypedActor create() {
          return myactor;
      }
  }));
```

Error during runtime:

> Caused by: akka.actor.ActorInitializationException:   You cannot create
>   an instance of [com.practice.MyActor] explicitly using the constructor
>   (new).    You have to use one of the factory methods to create a new
>   actor. Either use:        'val actor = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor])'
>   (to create a supervised child actor from within an actor), or         'val
>   actor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor(..)))' (to create a top level
>   actor from the ActorSystem)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are creating the instance of `MyActor` outside the `ActorSystem`. Create the Actor inside of your factory (that's what it is for ;-) ) and it should be fine.

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("mynamespace");
ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
  public UntypedActor create() {
    return new MyActor();
  }
}));
```

In this case you don't even need a factory, because you have a default constructor. Just pass the class as parameter to the `Props`:

```
system.actorOf(new Props(MyActor.class));
```

Comment: Thanks Dexrin.It worked. I have to get hold of the reference to new MyActor() and now I am initializing the reference within create() method.