# Error creating child actor

Tags: akka, actor

In an Actor I create a child actor like below

```
ActorRef sessionEventHandlerActor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(SessionHandler.class), sessionId);
```

and this is SessionHandler actor:

```
public class SessionHandler extends UntypedActor {

    public SessionHandler() {
        getContext().setReceiveTimeout(Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {


     }
}
```

and I get following error:

```
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [actors.SessionHandler] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.$init$(Actor.scala:421)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.<init>(UntypedActor.scala:97)
    at org.esi.actors.SessionHandler.<init>(SessionHandler.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:45)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(Props.scala:358)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:249)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
```

I do not see any issue in how I create the actor. Does any one know what the problem can be?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735716/unable-to-create-an-actor-using-untypedactorfactory-of-akka-java-api

Comment: @BranislavLazic Thanks, but as you see in my code, I am not creating the _actor outside of ActorSystem: getContext().actorOf(Props.create(SessionHandler.class), "name");_

Comment: What line(22) is the exception referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no problem anymore, but I think you need to leave out the the sessionId argument, because create will try to apply it to the constructor.

```
ActorRef sessionEventHandlerActor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(SessionHandler.class));
```

As far as I understood the Java API. I only used it in scala.